# Failed to construct websocket

Tags: javascript, docker, websocket, ionic3, mixed-content

When running the application on the browser I saw this error in the console.

I have dockerized my application and using nginx proxy for https.

I know it is asking me to open the ports 53703, but I am not getting where to open the ports in aws or in docker run command? I am also using it through aws.

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xuz.xyz.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://xuz.xyz.com:53703/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS`.

```
 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
    at Object.openConnection (https://xuz.xyz.com/__ion-dev-server/ion-dev.js?v=2.0.2:101:19)
    at Object.start (https://xuz.xyz.com/__ion-dev-server/ion-dev.js?v=2.0.2:18:10)
    at https://xuz.xyz.com/__ion-dev-server/ion-dev.js?v=2.0.2:465:16
```

Note: I know the shield icon, but don't want to allow the insecure scripts.

Comment: The error message is saying you need to change the protocol part of the URL to `wss://`, right? (instead of just `ws://`…)

Comment: Either run your app on `http://` or move your socket to `wss://`

Comment: How to locate the socket ws:// so that I change to wss://